# Angular service watch creates $digest loop

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a `scope` to update when the return value of a service function changes. From reading, it sounds like I'm supposed to use `$watch`, but following the angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) creates an infinite `$digest` loop in my application, here the controller:

```
.controller('navCtrl', function(CookieHandler, $scope){
  // this works, but doesn't update when CookieHandler.get() changes
  // $scope.user = CookieHandler.get();

  $scope.$watch(
    function() {return CookieHandler.get()},
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if( newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.user = newValue
      }
    }
  ) 
  //etc
```

From the error message there's something about using $watch on functions that return an array, but `CookieHandler.get()` returns an object?

I looked around some more and read that I should use `$apply` instead of `$watch` here because it's easier to test, so I tried this:

```
.controller('navCtrl', function(CookieHandler, $scope){
  // this works, but doesn't update when CookieHandler.get() changes
  // $scope.user = CookieHandler.get();

  $scope.$apply(function(scope){
    scope.user = CookieHandler.get();
  })
})
```

But this throws an error about the digest cycle already running. Is there a way to fix my `$watch` to stop the infinite loop? `CookieHandler.get` just checks the value with `$cookieStore`

Comment: you use `$apply` when you are updating scope from outside of angular known events. It forces a digest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$watch` performs an equal comparison between the current value and the value from the previous digest cycle. If they are different then the function is executed.

If the object returned by `CookieHandler.get()` is always the same reference then the watch function will never get called. Even if you update properties of that object.

Arrays are a bad idea because they are often always a new object and JavaScript will see them as never equal.

You could serialize the object/array to JSON and use that value, but this won't work if there are changes in key/value orders.

It looks like you are trying to monitor when the current user is changed. Assuming you have a unique identifier for a user, then you might want to try something like this.

```
$scope.$watch(
  function() {
      var user = CookieHandler.get();
      return (typeof user === 'undefined') ? 0 : user.id;
  },
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if( newValue !== oldValue) {
      $scope.user = CookieHandler.get();
    }
  }
);
```

Note that I call `.get()` twice. I don't know how your service works. Maybe that's not possible, but the point is to watch a value that is easily comparable.

Comment: great, that works and is a step in the right direction, although it seems to be flaky on page refreshes for some reason. It gives me something to start with though, thanks! I'm not sure I understand the ternary operator. Basically, the watcher is setup on `user.id` and gets set to 0 if `user.id` is undefined. So then everytime the `$digest` cycle runs, this watcher checks to see if CookieHandler.get() returns a new value for `user.id`?

Comment: @user2936314 yea, I wasn't sure what `get()` returned. So I was just assuming you were using integers for ids, and defaulted undefined to 0. The basic idea is to ensure that watch uses comparable values. Objects/Arrays are not easily comparable in JS. String/number are much easier to work with for watcher.